# Pygame - Play sounds simultaneously

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am making a Game using Pygame and what I'm trying to do is to have a main sound for every level and some default sounds being heard when collecting points (e.g.)

So, I load the main level music using:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Now, what I want to do is to play a specific sound whenever a player collects a point. I cannot stop the music using:

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
pygame.mixer.music.load(point_music)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

because the level's music will stop playing.

So, I've tried doing something like this:

```
points_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("point.mp3")
points_sound.play()
```

I know that sound playing in pygame runs on its own thread but I am sure that the program/game does not terminate prior to finish playing the sound.

Long story short: The player can collect points but I am unable to make pygame play the collecting points sound.

Comment: `points_sound.play()` looks good, Is there a problem with that soulution?

Comment: Docs say mp3 support is limited for `music` and that only OGG and WAV are supported for `Sound`.  Have you tried one of the formats that are officially supported?

Comment: sr2222 please give it as an answer so as to mark the thread as solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [sr2222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810233/pygame-play-sounds-simultaneously#comment19000434_13810233) said in comments:

> Docs say mp3 support is limited for music and that only OGG and WAV
>   are supported for Sound. Have you tried one of the formats that are
>   officially supported?

Try out OGG or WAV formats for your sounds instead, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

points_sound.play() should return a channel object. This object is necessary for playing the sound.

```
points_channel = points_sound.play()
```

This has me helped in my own case.