# How to use multiple instance of the same import module

Tags: python, multithreading, module, pygame

I want to use the import module in 2 separate instances

[python]

```
import pygame
[...]
player1 = pygame.mixer
player1.init()
player1.music.load('file1.mp3')    
player1.music.play()
[...]
player2 = pygame.mixer
player2.init()
player2.music.load('file2.mp3')    
player2.music.play()
```

i want to play file1.mp3 and file2.mp3 at the same time but this way of coding starts to play file1.mp3 then start to play file2.mp3 (file1.mp3 is stopped)
i want to play them both simultaneously not one then the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kind of limitation of pygame with .mp3 format files to reproduce sounds in parallel. I found this information here: [Pygame - Play sounds simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810233/pygame-play-sounds-simultaneously)

To achieve your results, it's necessary change the format from .mp3 to .wav or .ogg

See the example below:

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()

sounds = [pygame.mixer.Sound('file1.wav'),
          pygame.mixer.Sound('file2.wav')]
channels = [sound.play() for sound in sounds]

while any(channel.get_busy() for channel in channels):
    print('Playing ...')
    pygame.time.wait(100)

print('Finished')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your head up, i'm misusing the pygame stuff, there is channel management to do on pygame.mixer.music to play multiple track at once.
pygame.mixer.Sound() is easier to use as multiple instances are OK, 
still is seems there is an issue concerning mp3 playback, play 1 mp3 at a time is ok, playing 2 at once crash or behave as described before.